# Swift error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression;

Tags: diagnostics

> Error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a
> bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

I do not seem to find the problem. if you know how I can fix it please help.

The error is on the: var body: some View { code

This is the code:

```
    import SwiftUI
    import MapKit

    struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var controller = ContentController()
    @StateObject private var parkingController = ParkingController()
    @State private var selectedLocation: ParkingLocation? = nil

    @State private var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $controller.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation:          true, userTrackingMode: $controller.userTrackingMode, annotationItems: parkingController.parkingLocations) { location in
                MapMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude), tint: location.isAvailable ? .green : .red)
                
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { scale in
                    controller.zoom(scale)
                }
        )
        
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        controller.toggleUserTrackingMode()
                        parkingController.updateParkingAvailability()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "location.circle.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    Menu{
                        Button("Cancel", role: .destructive){
                        }
                        Button{
                            
                        }label: {
                            Label("Park Out", systemImage: "car.side.fill")
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            if let userLocation = userLocation {
                                if let nearestLocation = parkingController.findNearestLocation(userLocation: userLocation) {
                                    parkingController.decreaseAvailability(location: nearestLocation)
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            Label("Park In", systemImage: "car.side.fill")
                        }
                        Button {
                            //do something
                        }label: {
                            Label("Add parking", systemImage: "plus")
                            
                        }
                    }
                    label : {
                        Label("", systemImage: "car")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        )
        
        .onAppear {
            controller.requestLocationAuthorization()
            locationManager.delegate = controller
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        .onChange(of: controller.userLocation) { location in
            userLocation = location?.coordinate
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ContentView()
.onAppear {
let controller = ContentController()
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
controller.locationManager = locationManager
locationManager.delegate = controller
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
}
}
```

I tried to look at syntax and missing } but there are none.